# Attributes in External Assemblies

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have been moving some common attributes into a separate vs project, so that I can easily use them in multiple projects.  One of the attributes is for webapi controllers and ensures the request is using HTTPS:

```
public class EnsureHttpsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if(actionContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("actionContext");
        }

        if(actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
        {
            HandleNonHttpsRequest(actionContext);
        }
    }

    protected virtual HttpResponseMessage HandleNonHttpsRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;

        if(actionContext.Request.Method.Equals(HttpMethod.Get) || actionContext.Request.Method.Equals(HttpMethod.Head))
        {
            UriBuilder newUrlBuilder = new UriBuilder(actionContext.Request.RequestUri);
            newUrlBuilder.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps;
            newUrlBuilder.Port = 443;

            response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Found);

            response.Headers.Location = newUrlBuilder.Uri;
        }
        else
        {
            response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        actionContext.Response = response;

        return response;
    }

    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
    {
        if(actionContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("actionContext");
        }

        if(actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
        {
            return Task.FromResult<HttpResponseMessage>(HandleNonHttpsRequest(actionContext));
        }
        else
        {
            return continuation();
        }
    }
}
```

I then add the attribute as follows:

```
config.Filters.Add(new EnsureHttpsAttribute());
```

The problem is that when the attribute is reference from a separate project, it does not get called.  The project compiles and runs without issue - except that the attribute does not get executed.  If I move the attribute into the same webapi project, the attribute will get executed.  I have other attributes which use claims to authorise the request - these don't get executed either when part of a separate project.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Works like a charm for me, are you sure you use the same System.Web.Http and System.Net.Http version in both projects?

Comment: @JosVinke Thanks for the reply.  I created a new web api project and tried consuming the separate project - it worked as expected.  I did notice that in both this new project and the original that there was a miss-match on the version of System.Web.Http (4.0.0.0 and 5.2.3.0) - I updated the projects so they all consumed 5.2.3.0 and everything is now working. Do you know why this may have caused a problem?  I would have expected an exception.

Comment: Good to read it's working now, I don't know however what causes the problem. There is quite a difference between the ActionFilterAttribute implementation  from version 4.0.0.0 and 5.2.3.0 (For example the addition of the Async methods) but I'm not sure what causes the problem exactly could also be some change in the HTTP pipeline. If you figure it out, please let me know.

Comment: I'll add the solution as an answer (instead of a comment) for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible to put your Attributes in an external project.

Please make sure that you are using the same **System.Web.Http** and **System.Net.Http** version in both projects.